# List remote SQL databases without client software

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell

I'd like to have a PowerShell script that uses as input;

```
-username 
-password
-remote servername
```

And then lists the remote SQL databases. Thing is, it should work from any PC with powershell, even if there are no SQL client/tools used/installed/plugins loaded. Standard .NET framework call are accepted ofcourse.

I know it's possible, because I've seen 'sql-clientless' machines list databases remotely.

Comment: Look at the answer to this question, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80264/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-discover-all-running-instances-of-sql-server-u. It might be a start for you.

Comment: I don't want to discover, I want to ennumerate the databases on a certian server.

Comment: It's a start :) Once you have the list of instance name you can use Get-WmiObject win32_perfformatteddata_mssqlserver_sqlserverdatabases.This would list the default instance databases. Replace mssqlserver with the discovered instances. I don't think that requires any SQL client tools to be installed.

Comment: No, discovery is something I don't want. There is a big bad firewall in between, and I already know the servername containing the databases. I just need to list them.

Comment: @Lectere what do you mean "without client software"? ADO.NET already contains the SQL Server client provider. You don't need any other client software. Using the SQL Server Powershell module just makes life easier

Comment: I mean that I want to try to connect to SQL without using plugin's other than installed on a default 2012 or 2016 server. So, framework is installed, so that's usable...

Comment: As for listing the databases, just execute `SELECT * from sys.databases`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work with an *installed .NET Framework*:

```
function Get-SqlDatabases
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        $Server,
        $User,
        $Password
    )

    $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "Data Source=$Server;User ID=$User;Password=$Password"
    $sqlConnection.Open();
    $sqlConnection.GetSchema("Databases") | select -expand database_name
    $sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Get-SqlDatabases -Server 'myServer' -User 'myUser' -Password 'mySecret'
```

Comment: This works because the client is already there as part of ADO.NET

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True, I changed the text.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, thnx